# Cytoscape.js cy.load() becomes slower

Tags: cytoscape.js

i'm using Cytoscape.js in combination with the Vaadin Framework.
Now i have a Problem during Testing.

i tried to measured the time, the load() function takes.
this is my code:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();  
cy.load(eles);  
cy.fit();  
var end = new Date().getTime();  
var time = end-start;
```

eles are my Elements.
I repeat this with an setInterval().
The Problem is, the function becomes slower and slower with each iteration.
Whats the Problem? Where is my error?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

`cy.load()` is an asynchronous function, so you're going to run into issues if you try to load again before the previous load has finished.  Have you tried using the callbacks on load done?  It seems that using an interval is the wrong approach unless you have some method of keeping track of successive load progress.